# How to change default terminal's name to something dynamic in IntelliJ?

Tags: intellij-idea

I have been using IntelliJ's integrated terminal quite a lot recently. More often than not, I have 10+ tabs open. I was looking for a way to rename the said tab based on the current directory. It gets really confusing to have so many tabs, so I have to resort to manually rename each tab by right clicking and doing "rename session". E.g.:

[image]

***Is there a way to setup the terminal tab name in IntelliJ to something dynamic/configurable based on a script or anything smarter than a static string?***

Things I've tried:

- E.g. something like `echo -ne "\e]1;$PWD\a"`, which was discussed in
  [this answer here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tzNJAm.png). However this doesn't yield any results, and tab name remains unchanged.
- I have also tried setting the "Tab name" in IDEA's preferences, as seen below. I
  tried setting it to $(PWD), but that did not work. It remains stuck to that static string.

[image]

Comment: This doesn't appear to be possible currently... JetBrains got the [original feature request](https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/360000142484-Name-Terminal-with-PWD-?page=1#community_comment_360000084190) in 2018 and it [appears to still be open](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-146714?_ga=2.263751180.1845080866.1637179775-1021458372.1635438736)...

Comment: @eatsfood I am glad that I am not the only one suffering from this lack of feature :)